# Proper escaping for ng-init

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, jsp, escaping

I have a java web application with an angular.js app imported on a page. When the page is called, I gather a bunch of variables in the java class and build a JSONObject instance containing them.

```
JSONObject initData = new JSONObject();
initData.put("key1", "abc");
initData.put("test special chars", "$%{}<>'\"?");
request.setAttribute("initData", initData.toString());
```

I want the variables gathered in the java class to be available to the angular app, which is why I'm using a json object. In the jsp I have the following:

```
<div ng-app="myAngularApp" ng-init="initData=${initData}">
    <div class="ng-view"></div>
</div>

<script src="angular/scripts/frameworks.js"></script>
<script src="angular/scripts/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="angular/scripts/myApp.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">angular.modulate.instantiateModules();</script>
```

The `${initData}` prints out the string value of my JSONObject from the java class. However, I can't seem to escape it correctly. I've tried a bunch of StringEscapeUtils methods but no luck.

What's the correct way to get this info into ng-init?

Comment: any thought on using controller rather than ng-init?

Comment: The angular app is imported from a separate project. So would using the controller be possible?

Comment: I edited to illustrate that my app is an outside resource so putting ${initData} in the controller isn't an option

Comment: just create a global javascript variable and print your data as it's value. No need for ng-init. A simple service or controller can read the global variable

Comment: That was my first strategy. But I run the angular app standalone during development. If I define the global variable in the jsp, I then have to do a try-catch in angular to handle running it alone when that variable would not exist. That seemed too goofy, so I was wondering if there's a "right" way to accomplish this. But if not, I'll be reverting back to that strategy.